# PyCharm: area with code is all gray. How can I see my code?

Tags: pycharm

Why do I no longer see my code in PyCharm? I can run the code, but I don't see it. Instead, the area where the code is normally displayed is all gray.

[image]

Comment: There is probably a fatal error in the log (**Help | Show Log in ...***). I suggest sending it to pycharm-support@jetbrains.com